# Displaying column of MySQL database in a combobox in WPF? I'm only getting 'System.Data.DataRowView' displayed

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to get the values in a table's column to populate the options of a combobox. Whenever I try, the combobox fills with the correct amount of options, but instead of the column's values, the options are all 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

XAML

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Height="42" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

C#

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string connectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=dbname; UID=myPC;Password=myPW;";

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select columnname from tablename", connection);
    connection.Open();


    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    connection.Close();

    ComboBox_1.DataContext = dt;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the DisplayMemberPath like this.

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="YourColumnName"/>
```

And set ComboBox's ItemsSource as dt.DefaultView like this.

```
ComboBox_1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

You can show only one column in the ComboBox. If you want to show all the columns, you can use a DataGrid instead or define an ItemTemplate for ComboBox.